# Sidebar menu hide from users using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner at laravel and I have Hidden sidebar menu from users it's successfully working but when logout from admin then I face error how to fix it thanks. please see error https://flareapp.io/share/NPL9bz7w

**Html view**

```
             <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
             <nav class="mt-2">
             <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" 
              role="menu" data-accordion="false">
             <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
             with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->   
             <!--Admin sidebar menu -->
             @if(Auth::user()->type  == "admin")
             <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{url('admin')}}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
            <p>Users Permission</p>
            </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{url('manage_users')}}" class="nav-link">
            <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
             <p>Manage Users</p>
            </a>
           </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="{{url('register')}}" class="nav-link">
           <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
           <p> User Register</p>
           </a>
           </li>
           <!-- end Admin sidebar menu -->
           <!--   User sidebar menu -->
           @else
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="{{url('viewprofile')}}" class="nav-link">
          <i class="fas fa-user">  </i>
          <p>View Profile</p>
          </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="{{url('DashBoard')}}" class="nav-link">
           <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
           <p>Chat Room</p>
           </a>
          </li>

          @endif




    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you are checking `@if(Auth::user()->type  == "admin")` for check the logged in admin. If the admin is logged out then there is no `Auth::user()`. I think this is the problem you are facing. So change the condition like this

```
 @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type  == "admin")
    // Admin menu bar
 @elseif (Auth::check())
    // User menu bar
 @endif
```

I think this will solve the issue.

Comment: please check it https://flareapp.io/share/NPG0MM7G#F47 when I logout from admin thanks.

Comment: $user_permission = Users_Permissions::with('user')->Where('user_id',Auth::user()->id). This is the same problem i mentioned in the answer. If the user is logged out, then Auth::user() is null

Comment: Here you are trying to get the property id from a null value

Answer (score 1):

Since the user is logged out, the **Auth::user()** is null.

Because of which, when you try to get its type, it is throwing

> Trying to get property 'type' of non-object

You need to check whether the user is logged in, and then check its type.

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type  == "admin")
```

**Auth::check()** will return true if the user is logged in

Answer (score 0):

first check **if user logged in** then check that **if user is admin or not**:

```
         <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
         <nav class="mt-2">
         <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" 
          role="menu" data-accordion="false">
         <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
         with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->   
         <!--Admin sidebar menu -->
         @auth
         @if(Auth::user()->type  == "admin")
         <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{url('admin')}}" class="nav-link">
        <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
        <p>Users Permission</p>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="{{url('manage_users')}}" class="nav-link">
        <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
         <p>Manage Users</p>
        </a>
       </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="{{url('register')}}" class="nav-link">
       <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
       <p> User Register</p>
       </a>
       </li>
       <!-- end Admin sidebar menu -->
       <!--   User sidebar menu -->
       @else
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="{{url('viewprofile')}}" class="nav-link">
      <i class="fas fa-user">  </i>
      <p>View Profile</p>
      </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="{{url('DashBoard')}}" class="nav-link">
       <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
       <p>Chat Room</p>
       </a>
      </li>

      @endif
      @endauth




</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use isset method

```
@if(isset(Auth::user()->type) && Auth::user()->type== "admin")
```

you can also use Auth::check()

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type== "admin")
```